# PHP sometimes relative links work sometimes they don't?

Tags: php, directory, structure, require, relative-path

Okay so this is my project structure (simplified):

```
+blog
  -index.php //Index 2
  + views
    -index.php // Index 3
    -article.php
-index.php // Index 1
+partials
  -constants.php
  -top.php
```

Okay so in **Index 1** and **Index 2** I use this line of code to include some partials/snippets:

**Index 1**:

```
<?php require_once("./partials/constants.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("./partials/top.php"); ?>
```

**Index 2**:

```
<?php require_once("../partials/constants.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../partials/top.php"); ?>
```

but in **Index 3** if I use this:

```
<?php require_once(".../partials/constants.php"); ?>
<?php require_once(".../partials/top.php"); ?>
```

I receive this error:

```
<body><br>
<b>Warning</b>:  require_once(.../partials/constants.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/codio/workspace/blog/views/index.php</b> on line <b>1</b><br>
<br>
<b>Fatal error</b>:  require_once(): Failed opening required '.../partials/constants.php' (include_path='.:/home/codio/.parts/packages/php5-apache2/5.5.15/lib/php') in <b>/home/codio/workspace/blog/views/index.php</b> on line <b>1</b><br>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those dots before the file path doesn't mean the level of the directory.

`./` reference the same directory you are

`../` a level above.

That said, you should be running `../../partials/constants.php` on index3

For index2, as it is a level above index3, you need to change the require statement to `../partials/constants.php`

And for index, as it is in the same level of directory `partials` you would run `require ('partials/constants.php');`

Comment: YOU BEAUTY Cheers fir that, I never knew :)

Comment: Although now on the page about **Index 2** I get this error:
``{"type":64,"message":"require_once(): Failed opening required '..\/..\/partials\/constants.php' (include_path='.:\/home\/codio\/.parts\/packages\/php5-apache2\/5.5.15\/lib\/php')","file":"\/home\/codio\/workspace\/blog\/views\/index.php","line":1}``

Comment: That's because index2, is just a level inside, so for index2 you want to use `../partials/constants.php`.

Comment: was doing that but no stress us actually something else :)